# Aggregation stage not supported: '$bucket'

Tags: aggregation-framework, bucket, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I am using mongodb and querying a db using bucket stage with aggregation.
mongodb version :

```
db.serverBuildInfo()
{ 
    "version" : "3.6.0", 
    "versionArray" : [
        3.0, 
        6.0, 
        0.0, 
        0.0
    ], 
    "bits" : 64.0, 
    "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216.0, 
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

My query is :

```
db.data.aggregate(
[    
    {
        "$bucket": 
        {
            groupBy: "$h_id",
            boundaries: [ 0, 100, 200, 300],
            default: "Other",
            output: {
                "count": { $sum: 1 },
            }
        }
    },
]);
```

I am getting error:

> Unable to execute the selected commands
>
> Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error
>   304: 'Aggregation stage not supported: '$bucket'' on server
>   mongodb-test:27017.
>
> The full response is: { 
>       "ok" : 0.0, 
>       "errmsg" : "Aggregation stage not supported: '$bucket'", 
>       "code" : NumberInt(304) }

In document I can see that bucket is included in mongodb from version 3.4.
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/

Can any body point out what is the reason of this error...

Comment: Are you able to use other aggregation stages like `$group`, etc.

Comment: @prasad_: Yes, I am able to use match, group, sort, unwind ...

Comment: This isn't a MongoDB server error code or message. It looks like you are using an emulated API (likely DocumentDB) which currently does not support the `$bucket` operator.

Comment: @Stennie: mongodb shell is also giving same error : 
rs0:PRIMARY> db.data.aggregate(
... [    
...     {
...         "$bucket": 
...         {
...             groupBy: "$h_id",
...             boundaries: [ 0, 100, 200, 300],
...             default: "Other",
...             output: {
...                 "count": { $sum: 1 },
...             }
...         }
...     },
... ]);
assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Aggregation stage not supported: '$bucket'",
 "code" : 304
} : aggregate failed

Comment: The error message is coming from the server you are connecting to, but since that isn't a MongoDB server message I'm guessing you are using an emulated service (which will differ in feature support). Based on the error message and incomplete `db.serverBuildInfo()` this looks like AWS DocumentDB, which does not currently have support for `$bucket` and many other aggregation operators and stages: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html#mongo-apis-aggregation-pipeline-stage.

Comment: @Stennie: OK understood, this is why getting error message. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Amazon DocumentDB, several MongoDB aggregation operators, such as $bucket, $facet, and others, commonly used in MongoDB, are not supported. Amazon DocumentDB offers compatibility with a subset of MongoDB APIs and features, but certain functionalities might differ or not be available.

For more information on MongoDB APIs supported by Amazon DocumentDB, you can refer to the official documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html).